# In Python is a, b, = 0, 0 semantically identical to a = b = 0

Tags: python, variables, initialization, semantics

Question same as above: I'm curious what the difference is between `a, b, = [], []` and `a = b = []` is (if any)

Comment: The former assigns two different empty lists to `a` and `b`.  The latter assigns a reference to the same empty list to both `a` and `b`.  If you subsequently modify one of the lists, the former will only show the change in one of the variables, while the latter will show it in both.

Comment: @TomKarzes thank you, is there a simpler way for me to write something like  a, b, c, d, e= [], [], [], [], [] while still assigning each variable to a new distinct list?

Comment: What's wrong with `a, b, c, d, e = [], [], [], [], []`? Maybe you should ask if you really need that many variables or if your task can be solved using another data structure, such as a dict or a list of lists.

Comment: If you're going up to 5 or more lists, then you might consider switching to a list of lists.  Then could do `list_of_lists = [[] for _ in range(n)]` to set `list_of_lists` to `n` empty sub-lists.

Answer (score 3):

The difference is that doing:

```
l = [1, 2, 3]
a = b = l.copy()
```

Would still make `a` and `b` reference to the same object, whereas doing:

```
l = [1, 2, 3]
a, b = l.copy(), l.copy()
```

Won't.

Example:

```
>>> l = [1, 2, 3]
>>> a = b = l.copy()
>>> a
[1, 2, 3]
>>> b
[1, 2, 3]
>>> a[0] = 100
>>> a
[100, 2, 3]
>>> b
[100, 2, 3]
>>>
```

---

```
>>> a, b = l.copy(), l.copy()
>>> a
[1, 2, 3]
>>> b
[1, 2, 3]
>>> a[0] = 100
>>> a
[100, 2, 3]
>>> b
[1, 2, 3]
>>>
```

---

It's also provable with your example:

```
>>> a = b = []
>>> id(a)
1666229809344
>>> id(b)
1666229809344
>>> a, b, = [], []
>>> id(a)
1666230083712
>>> id(b)
1666230079296
>>>
```

Using `a = b = []` makes the two variables reference to the same object.

Comment: Thank you, is there a simpler way for me to write something like a, b, c, d, e= [], [], [], [], [] while still assigning each variable to a new distinct list?

Comment: Maybe use a list comprehension: `a, b, c, d, e = [[] for _ in range(5)]`

Comment: @GoldinGuy Did you see the message?